# R: Point colours determined by X, Y and Z values with scatterplot3d

Tags: r

I have this R script that uses `scatterplot3d`:

```r
library(scatterplot3d)
attach(mtcars)

rgb <- read.csv(file="rgb-data.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")

scatterplot3d(rgb$R,rgb$G,rgb$B,
              xlim=c(0,255), ylim=c(0,255),zlim=c(0,255),
              xlab="R", ylab="G", zlab="B", pch=".",
              main=paste("Feature Space"))
```

Sample data for `rgb-data.csv` is:

```
R,G,B
12,48,126
127,12,48
46,127,12
```

It produces the plot:

[image]

I'm looking for 4 changes:

1. Have the (0,0,0) point being the front most point in the cube, most central, rather than the point in the bottom left of the plot. Is this possible?
2. Have the colour of each point reflect the R, G and B values of each point. E.g. `(12,48,126)` in the above dataset, the R value of the point is 12, G is 48 and B is 126. Is this possible?
3. The X, Y and Z axis range from 0 to 255 in the R script. However, in the plot they range from 0 to 300. I'd like the axis ranges to be 0 to 255 in the generated plot. Is this possible?
4. The "B" and "G" axis labels are rotated 270 degrees. I'd like them the same orientation as the "R" axis label. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the 1st question correctly. But, here's the code.

1. Control with `xlim`, `ylim`, `zlim`
2. Use RGB function (note that you probably need to change your variable name since the function is called `rgb`)
3. Control with `x.ticklabs`, `y.ticklabs`, `z.ticklabs`

**The code**

```
library(scatterplot3d)

R <- sample(0:255, 100)
G <- sample(0:255, 100)
B <- sample(0:255, 100)

RGB_ <- rgb(R/255, G/255, B/255)

r_ticks <- c(-255, -200, -100, 0, 100, 200, 255)
ticks <- c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 255)
scatterplot3d(R, G, B,
              xlim=c(-255, 255),
              ylim=c(0, 255),
              zlim=c(0, 255),
              color=RGB_,
              x.ticklabs=r_ticks,
              y.ticklabs=ticks,
              z.ticklabs=ticks)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Have the (0,0,0) point being the front most point in the cube, most central, rather than the point in the bottom left of the plot. Is this possible?

Setting `angle=140` in `scatterplot3d( )` provided something close the desired plot:

[image]

The (0,0,0) position is more central at the bottom of the plot. I was also envisaging the R and G axes to be sloped slightly upwards into the distance from 0 to 255.

> 2. Have the colour of each point reflect the R, G and B values of each point. E.g. (12,48,126) in the above dataset, the R value of the point is 12, G is 48 and B is 126. Is this possible?

Based on Mo K's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45655505/1526266), adding

```
color=rgb(dat$R, dat$G, dat$B, maxColorValue = 255)
```

to `scatterplot3d( )` gives the desired effect, provided renaming the original variable to `dat` i.e.

```
dat <- read.csv(file="rgb-data.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
```

> 3. The X, Y and Z axis range from 0 to 255 in the R script. However, in the plot they range from 0 to 300. I'd like the axis ranges to be 0 to 255 in the generated plot. Is this possible?

Mo K's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45655505/1526266) works. Adding

```
ticks <- c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 255)
```

Then

```
x.ticklabs=ticks,
y.ticklabs=ticks,
z.ticklabs=ticks
```

to `scatterplots3d( )`.

> 4. The "B" and "G" axis labels are rotated 270 degrees. I'd like them the same orientation as the "R" axis label. Is this possible?

I haven't found a solution to this yet.